# Can't create a new Rails application. Sqlite3 won't install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

Error message:

```
Installing sqlite3 (1.3.7) with native extensions <br>
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.<br>

    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for sqlite3.h... yes<br>
checking for sqlite3_libversion_number() in -lsqlite3... yes<br>
checking for rb_proc_arity()... yes<br>
checking for sqlite3_initialize()... yes<br>
checking for sqlite3_backup_init()... yes<br>
checking for sqlite3_column_database_name()... no<br>
checking for sqlite3_enable_load_extension()... yes<br>
checking for sqlite3_load_extension()... yes<br>
checking for sqlite3_open_v2()... yes<br>
checking for sqlite3_prepare_v2()... yes<br>
checking for sqlite3_int64 in sqlite3.h... yes<br>
checking for sqlite3_uint64 in sqlite3.h... yes<br>
creating Makefile<br>

make
compiling backup.c<br>
make: /robertmhirsch/bin/gcc.4.2: No such file or directory<br>
make: *** [backup.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7 for inspection.<br>
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out<br>
An error occured while installing sqlite3 (1.3.7), and Bundler cannot continue.<br>
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.7'` succeeds before bundling.<br>
```

Comment: I'm running OSX 10.8.2
GCC is installed here: usr/bin/gcc
GCC Version: gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)

I used RailsInstaller for the initial install

Comment: Your edit has made things bad @prakash-murthy

Comment: Updated the answer with a link for OSX @robert-hirsch

Comment: Disregard the <br> tags. Couldn't get it to display properly.

Comment: @ck No, prakash-murthy improved formating. Robert Hirsch should have added more text, explaining more of his situation.

Comment: I installed rails with RailsInstaller. Installation seemed to go fine. When I try to create a new rails application I get this error above. I just copied the part with the error. I've also tried installing devtools from apple, which didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install GCC or equivalent. You haven't mentioned what OS you are using, in case of Ubuntu, you can install necessary stuff by

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

For OSX refer to http://cczona.com/blog/2012/07/fix-for-make-usrbingcc-4-2-no-such-file-or-directory/

Comment: Tried the suggestions for OSX. This is what I get. ln: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2: File exists

Comment: I don't know much about OSX but from logs  `make: /robertmhirsch/bin/gcc.4.2: No such file or directory` while you commented `GCC is installed here: usr/bin/gcc GCC Version`
So I think something is wrong there.